# Add Native Ads to Flutter project using Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, admob, ads

I'm struggling with adding native ads in my flutter project .
My project is using Kotlin for android so I follow the documentation of google_mobile_ads
but it keeps showing me these errors after I used the recommendation of converting to kotlin by android studio.

```
e: reading_app\MainActivity.kt: (15, 113): No value passed for parameter 'layoutInflater'
e: reading_app\ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt: (15, 10): Class 'NativeAdFactoryExample' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun createNativeAd(p0: NativeAd!, p1: (Mutable)Map<String!, Any!>!): NativeAdView! defined in io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory
e: reading_app\ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt: (20, 68): Unresolved reference: my_native_ad
e: reading_app\ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt: (21, 63): Unresolved reference: ad_headline
e: reading_app\ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt: (22, 59): Unresolved reference: ad_body
```

Code in my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.reading_app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity


import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin;


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    @Override
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin())
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample", NativeAdFactoryExample())
    }

    @Override
    fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine?) {
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
    }
}
```

code in my ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt

```
package com.reading_app

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory
import java.util.Map


// my_native_ad.xml can be found at
/* https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/tree/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/android/app/src/main/res/layout
*/
internal class NativeAdFactoryExample(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater) : NativeAdFactory {
    private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater
    @Override
    fun createNativeAd(
            nativeAd: NativeAd, customOptions: Map<String?, Object?>?): NativeAdView {
        val adView: NativeAdView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_native_ad, null) as NativeAdView
        val headlineView: TextView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline)
        val bodyView: TextView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body)
        headlineView.setText(nativeAd.getHeadline())
        bodyView.setText(nativeAd.getBody())
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
        adView.setBodyView(bodyView)
        adView.setHeadlineView(headlineView)
        return adView
    }

    init {
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
code in my ReadingNativeAdFactory.kt
```

To

```
package com.reading_app

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory
import kotlin.collections.Map

internal class NativeAdFactoryLemoon(val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater) : NativeAdFactory {
    override fun createNativeAd(
        nativeAd: NativeAd, customOptions: Map<String, Any>?): NativeAdView  {
        val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_native_ad, null) as NativeAdView 
        val headlineView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_headline)
        val bodyView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_body)
        headlineView.text = nativeAd.headline
        bodyView.text = nativeAd.body
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
        adView.bodyView = bodyView
        adView.headlineView = headlineView
        return adView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just were troubling with the same error and I'll post my found here.
Your error is about LayoutInflater ; So you will need to change code in your MainActivity into something like this:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
@Override
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample", NativeAdFactoryExample( LayoutInflater.from(context)))
}

@Override
override fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
}
}
```

Comment: Dear OP, I am reviewer, please edit your question and place `}` in code blocks.